# Error while executing SQL scripts using powershell Command

Tags: powershell

I am using a `batch` file that calls a PowerShell file. During the execution of the script it gives this error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : The value's length for key 'initial catalog' exceeds
>   it's limit of '128'

**Code:**

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance "CUREMD-DB10"-InputFile "C:\DailyPatch\run.sql" -querytimeout([int]::MaxValue)| Out-File -filePath "C:\DailyPatch\dbname.txt" 
$text=Get-Content C:\DailyPatch\dbname.txt

$a = $text.length
$a=$a-3

$logFile = 'C:\DailyPatch\dblog.txt'

for ($i=3 ; $i -le $a ;$i++)
{   
    write-host $text[$i]
    $error.clear()

    foreach ($rr in $error) {
        $text[$i] >> $logFile
        $rr >> $logFile
    }   
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the contents to run.sql for further assistance.  Something there is exceeding the 128 character limit of 'initial catalog'

Comment: I belive thats something related with the connection to database. The serverinstance is used to have default instance? For default instances, only specify the computer name: "Computer". For named instances, use the format "ComputerName\InstanceName". Also to make a proper connection string for the wrapper(Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet in this case) you want to set the DataSource, InitialCatalog, UserId, and other properties individually.